# Matlab: Moving a percentage of one value to another in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
 t=3;
```

If I have matrix A (9x9xt):

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81
```

And vector B (9x1xt):

```
 0.5
 0.6
 0.7
 0.5
 0.6 
 0.7
 0.5
 0.6
 0.7


 for j=1:t
```

**I'm trying to move a percentage of A(7,1,j) into A(7,2,j+1). The percentage is B(3,1,j) in this case.**

I thought I should create a new value, m(1,1,j), which holds the percentage value: B(3,1,j) * A(7,1,j)...

```
      m(1,1,j)= A(7,1,j)*B(3,1,j); %# Find out what the percentage of A(7,1,j) is.
      A(7,2,j+1)= A(7,2,j)+m(1,1,j); %# Add that ''percentaged'' value to the A(7,2,j+1)
      A(7,1,j+1) = A(7,1,j)-m(1,1,j); %# Remove that ''percentaged'' value from A(7,1,j+1)
```

This, however, does not work. m(1,1,j) doesn't actually seem to equal A(7,1,j)*B(3,1,j) when I type ''m(1,1,j)''..

### Does anyone have a better and simple idea in how to move a percentage of one value in a matrix into another for the next timestep...That percentage must be removed from one value and added to the other.

Edit: Is this possible to complete in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are apparently two problems. First is the `j+1` in your last line (as indicated by @Sam). Second, you mistakenly increase the *j*-th item by `j*m(1,1,j)` and not by `m(1,1,j)`. This happens because you add to the next element, move next, and then you add the *accumulated* amount. A corrected vectorized version:

```
t=3;
A = repmat(reshape(1:81,9,9)',[1,1,t]);
B = repmat([0.5 0.6 0.7 0.5 0.6  0.7 0.5 0.6 0.7]', [1,1,t]);
m(1,1,1:t)= A(7,1,1:t).*B(3,1,1:t); %# Find out what the percentage of A(7,1,j) is.
A(:,:,t+1)=0; % Add zeros matrix at A(:,:,t+1)
A(7,2,2:t+1) = A(7,2,2:t+1)+m(1,1,1:t); %# Add that ''percentaged'' value to the A(7,2,j+1)
A(7,1,1:t) = A(7,1,1:t)-m(1,1,1:t); %# Remove that ''percentaged'' value from A(7,1,j+1)
```

Note: your original code also increases the size of A.

Answer (score 1):

Should your last line read:

```
A(7,1,j) = A(7,1,j)-m(1,1,j);
```

instead of

```
A(7,1,j+1) = A(7,1,j)-m(1,1,j);
```

As to whether there's a better way to do this - I'm not sure, as I'm not sure what you're ultimately trying to do. I would guess that if you're trying to carry out this operation for all rows, or all columns, or repeatedly in some other way, then there would be a vectorized way of doing it rather than a `for` loop.

Comment: The last line should technically be j+1 but it causes problems that cyborg highlighted below. Thank you for your time :)